# How do I resolve nested dependencies with run time parameters?

Tags: c#, autofac

How do I use Autofac to resolve nested dependencies that rely on runtime parameters?

For example:

```
class OrderService : IOrderService
{
  IInventoryService inventoryService;
  JobConfiguration configuration;

  OrderService(JobConfiguration configuration, IInventoryService inventoryService)
  {
    this.inventoryService = inventoryService;
    this.configuration = configuration;
  }

  DoSomething()
  {
    //here I can resolve the configuration values for the SFTPClient, so I want to call the Inventory service (that relies on the ISftpClient)
  }

class InventoryService : IInventoryService
{
  ISftpClient sftpClient;

  InventoryService(ISftpClient sftpClient)
  {
    this.sftpClient = sftpClient;
  }
}

class SftpClient : ISftpClient
{
  string host;
  string username;
  string password;

  SftpClient(string host, string username, string password)
  {
    this.host = host;
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password.
  }
}
```

If I want to resolve `IOrderService` (or have it passed in to another class), how would I resolve this whereby some of the dependencies rely on configuration values that I need to pass from a higher level.. deep in the object graph? This service could be many layers deep in the object graph.

I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45427236/what-is-the-best-way-to-pass-runtime-constructor-parameters-to-autofac/) question which suggested to use a factory for the SftpClient, but I can't see how this would work when the dependency is nested.

Comment: Please read [this article](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=99). Runtime values should typically not be injected into your components constructors.

Comment: If you call your `InventoryService` from `DoSomething()` method I understand you call some method from this service. So instead of creating (injecting) `ISmtpClient` in `InventoryService` you should inject your factory, pass parameters required by ISmtpClient from `DoSomething()` to `InventorySevice` method and create `ISmtpClient` with factory inside that method.